# export of QuickSteps in outlook

Tags: outlook

How to export the QuickSteps in excel ?

With no thirdparty programs. Is that possible ?

Thanks

I want to export the QuickSteps in outlook and import it in another user account

Answer (score 0):

**There is no trivial or straight way for doing that.** You can create a VBA macro or COM add-in to get this job for you. But a good knowledge of low-level programming is required for such tasks.

Quick steps are stored in a hidden folder named `Quick Step Settings` on the same level as the `Inbox` folder. Be aware, the name can be localized, so it is a good idea to open the folder by its entry id stored on the `PR_ADDITIONAL_REN_ENTRYIDS_EX` property on the `Inbox` folder.

The property contains multiple entry ids in a blob, the index of the `Quick Step Settings` folder is `RSF_PID_COMBINED_ACTIONS` (the property ID is 0x8007).

You are interested the hidden (associated) messages with the `IPM.Microsoft.CustomAction` message class. The associated messages can be accessed using [GetStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.getstorage) method of the `Folder` class. The `GetStorage` method obtains a [StorageItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.storageitem) on a `Folder` object using the identifier specified by `StorageIdentifier` and has the identifier type specified by `StorageIdentifierType`. The `StorageItem` is a hidden item in the `Folder`, which roams with the account and is available online and offline.

`QuickSteps` are stored as XML in `PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM` property, the DASL name is  `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C080102`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Steps are not directly exposed by the Outlook Object Model. You can access the raw MAPI data as Eugene outlined, but it will be your responsibility to correctly parse and reconstruct that data.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (it **is** a third party library, I am its author), it explicitly exposes Quick Steps through the [RDOQuickSteps](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoquicksteps.htm) object.

Either way, when you export and then import Quick Steps, you'd need to take care of correctly remapping the target folder entry ids: quick steps store the folder entry ids, which will be different on different machines, even if the names are the same.